# What is a hedge ratio tree?

Tags: finance

Determine the stock price tree, the call option tree, and the hedge ratio tree.

I have to make three separate trees for a european call option, I know what a stock price tree and a call option tree is but what information do I need to find to create a hedge ratio tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The optimal hedge ratio when hedging options using stocks is defined as the
ratio of option payoff change over the stock payoff change](http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/lwu/9797/lec5.pdf)

Comment: So it's basically the stock position? $\frac{\Delta C}{\Delta S}$

Comment: @idknuttin what's stock position? it is the ratio you said

Comment: Stock position is the ratio I stated, change in payoff over change in stock price. My textbook calls it stock position because it's the amount of stock the issuer of the call option should buy to make arbitrage